# How can I iterate over all queues registered in NestJs Bull?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, bull

I want to iterate over all queues registered in NestJs Bull and do something to each queue.

For example I already have this:

```
@Injectable()
export class BullUIProvider {
  constructor(@InjectQueue('backfill') private backfillQueue: Queue) {
    setQueues([new BullAdapter(backfillQueue)]);
  }
}
```

but I want to do something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class BullUIProvider {
  constructor(@Inject(queueProvider) private queues: QueueProvider) {
    setQueues(queues.map((queue) => new BullAdapter(queue)));
  }
}
```

Seems like I can only get at the queues one at a time using the name of the queue and only by using the @Inject decorator. Is there another way of getting at the queues?

Answer (score 1):

I did this to do what I wanted to do:

```
QUEUE_NAMES = ['queue-1', 'queue-2']

BullModule.registerQueue(
    ...QUEUE_NAMES.map(name => ({ name })),
  )
```

```
@Injectable()
export class BullService implements OnModuleInit {
  public queues: Queue[] = [];

  constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  onModuleInit(): any {
    this.queues = QUEUE_NAMES.map((name) =>
      this.moduleRef.get(getQueueToken(name), { strict: false }));
    setQueues(this.queues.map((queue) => new BullAdapter(queue)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I know it has been 2 years, but could you please add more details ? like where you got QUEUES_NAME. In order to help others seeking the answer.

Comment: QUEUE_NAMES is just a list of strings that I defined in a constants file. I use that list to register queues in the BullModule. I'll add that to the answer.